# running a batch file and checking if it has been modified

Tags: python, batch-file

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

def run_batch_file(batch_file_name):
    try:
        subprocess.run([batch_file_name], shell=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

def check_and_run_batch_file(batch_file_name, last_modified_time):
    current_modified_time = os.path.getmtime(batch_file_name)

    if current_modified_time > last_modified_time:
        print("Batch file has been modified. Running it...")
        run_batch_file(batch_file_name)
        return current_modified_time

    return last_modified_time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    batch_file_name = 'bat_file.bat'
    last_modified_time = 0

    while True:
        last_modified_time = check_and_run_batch_file(batch_file_name, last_modified_time)
        time.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second before checking again
```

Running the script launches the bat file successfully, but doesn't call it again even after updating it. Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: I only have Linux, but your code also works without modification to execute a bash script and executing it again if the bash script was modified. According to the documentation, `getmtime()` works identically under Linux and Windows, it should work the same way for you.